# cron job on specific time and date

Tags: php, cron, task

Hello i tried to create task in cron job to specific date and time.
i want that the task will work one time in: `05/04/2016 14:40 (dd/mm/yyyy h:i)`

how to do it?

i tried this:

```
36 2 5 4 * /usr/local/bin/php /home/#####/domains/####.com/public_html/cron/test.php
```

and

```
36 2 5 4 5 /usr/local/bin/php /home/#####/domains/####.com/public_html/cron/test.php
```

but its not worked...
and the path are good (other files work fine with other task)

tnx a lot

Comment: @Harikrishnan no no duplicate, my code are good but its not working

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
40 14 05 04 * /usr/local/bin/php /home/#####/domains/####.com/public_html/cron/test.php
```